# Concatenating two dataframes with no common columns but same row dimension

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two dataframes **df1** *(dimension: 2x3)* and **df2** *(dimension: 2x239)* taken for example - each having the same number of rows but a different number of columns.

I need to concatenate them to get a new dataframe **df3** *(dimension 2x242)*.

I used the *concat* function but ended up getting a (4x242) which has NaN values.

Need help.

Screenshot attached. [jupyter notebook screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By2Et.png)

Comment: @vogelstein That just changes the index values and has no effect on the dataframe. 
Here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/Z5KAgZm

Answer (score 0):

You need concat on columns, from your pic, `df2` index is duplicated. You need reset it to normal with `.reset_index(drop=True)`

```py
out = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.
Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/gZzTKRz

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the axis=1 parameter

```
pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()], axis=1)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: https://imgur.com/a/gZzTKRz

Comment: Do you have an index name same as a column name?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Edited with reset_index(). Can you check now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add these new columns in the same row. Try the below code :

```
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

The output shape will be (2*total_cols)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: https://imgur.com/a/gZzTKRz